# How to connect a server in simple tunnel?

Tags: ios, swift

```
NEVPNManager.sharedManager().enabled = true
        NEVPNManager.sharedManager().loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler{ error in
        print("error",error)
        if error == nil {
            let p = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
            p.serverAddress = "116.65.79.28"
            p.authenticationMethod = .SharedSecret
            p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
            let secret = "vpn"
            let secretData = secret.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            p.sharedSecretReference = secretData
            p.localIdentifier = "vpn"
            p.username = "vpn"
            p.passwordReference = "vpn".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)//SSKeychain.passwordForService("service", account: "passwordReference").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            p.disconnectOnSleep = false
            NEVPNManager.sharedManager().protocolConfiguration = p
            var rules = [NEOnDemandRule]()
            let connectRule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
            rules.append(connectRule)
            NEVPNManager.sharedManager().onDemandRules = rules
            NEVPNManager.sharedManager().localizedDescription = "vpn"

            NEVPNManager.sharedManager().enabled = true
            NEVPNManager.sharedManager().saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler{(error) in
                print("Save VPN to preference complete")
                if (error != nil) {
                    print("Save error: \(error)")
                }
                do {
                    try NEVPNManager.sharedManager().connection.startVPNTunnel()
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Start error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }



        }
}
```

[https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimpleTunnel/Introduction/Intro.html]

I am new to vpn connection. I don't know how to connect and run the example provided by apple.

I got the entitlements from the apple. The app is working but nothing is connecting. It doesn't move after the "targetManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()" in StatusViewController. I didn't get any clue to do this and i don't know how to do. please help me to get success.

So I tried run at least the above example. But i also not working... what to do?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleTunnel/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016140-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2